Loading Library multiple times is slow - what to do?
I am currently loading a library like this:
with bpy.data.libraries.load("//Library.blend") as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.materials = data_from.materials
sphere.data.materials.append(data_to.materials[0])

the problem I am having is that this is in a for loop, which it slows down pretty badly... I could of course move it out of there, but it would still run multiple times (because its in an operator). What would be the go-to way of only doing this work once per.. blend file?
Thanks :D
